# Swift Error Handling - Struct/Class vs Enum

Tags: ios, swift, struct, error-handling, enums

I am trying to model the possible errors that can be returned by the API I'm consuming and also possible network errors.

I'm struggling to figure out if I should use the `Struct/Class` approach, where each type of error is modeled as a `Struct/Class`, or the `Enum` approach.

Here are some notes to take into consideration:

1. Depending on what goes wrong, the same API call can return different errors with different `media-types` (so different JSON). So my errors have different properties. I don't want to expose the request response as a simple JSON Object / Dictionary.
2. I want the errors caused by a Client/Server issue to have a `httpStatusCode` property as well (it will be nil for errors that are related to no connectivity)
3. I want to have an error that indicates a connectivity issue with a proper localized message.
4. I want to use the same errors for both `sync` calls (used with `throws`) and `async` calls (used as a parameter in the completion block)

Mainly because of the first requirement it's pretty hard to figure out how to go down the `Enum` way. But maybe I'm missing something, maybe there still is some power that lays in the `Enum` types that I am not aware of.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Often `enum` is the best approach to deal with errors on Swift. To deliver different types you can use associated values and for a localized description you can implement `LocalizedError` protocol for your enum  e.g:

```
enum NetworkError : Error, LocalizedError {
    case noInternet
    case httpStatus(Int)
    case unknown(Error)
    
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
            case .noInternet:
                return "No Internet"
                
            case .httpStatus(let code):
                return "HTTP status code: \(code)"
                
            case .unknown(let error):
                return "Error: \(error)"
        }
    }
}

let err1 = NetworkError.noInternet
print(err1.localizedDescription)

let err2 = NetworkError.httpStatus(404)
print(err2.localizedDescription)

let err3 = NetworkError.unknown(error)
print(err3.localizedDescription)

/*
Prints:

No Internet
HTTP status code: 404
Error: error
*/
```

But if you have common data for your errors you should implement `struct` that holds needed properties with a type of your error:

```
struct ResponseError: Error {
    enum ErrorType {
        case badStatusCode
        case noJson
        case invalidJson(Error)
    }

    let type: ErrorType
    let statusCode: Int
}

let err = ResponseError(type: .badStatusCode, statusCode: 404)
```

Read more from the documentation about: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your end goal is (a little unclear to me), you can do combinations of `Struct`/`Class`, and `Enum`.

E.g. you could create a `Struct` that holds your information, and then create an `Enum` which then has a value of that `Struct`. Plus you can create functions in your `Enum`, if needed. There's a lot of functionality in `Enums` in Swift.

If you would like, you can also make a specific `Enum` value dependent on another `Enum`, or even change which `Struct`/`Class` each value is dependent on.

For more information on `Enums` look at apples [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html).